# Removing first empty rows and reindexing columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm receiving the data in excel. Sometimes, there will be blank rows and the data starts with columns from the sheet. Sometimes, there will be no blanks. straight the data will be available without any blanks.

However I'm using the below code snippet to remove blanks and reindex the columns

```
df = pd.read_excel(response.content, index_col=None)
df = df.dropna(how="all").dropna(how="all", axis=1)
headers = df.iloc[0]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)
print(new_df)
```

It'll work only if there are empty rows. It won't work if the data is coming without blanks. How can I handle this dynmamically?

Example Data

Sample 1

[image: sample data 1]

Result is

[image: Output]

[image]

Sample 2

[image]

Result is

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works fine if there is no blanks space also. Do you have any example where you are facing issue. That would be helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: I edited with sample data screenshots and outputs as well.

Comment: I'm facing the issue with reindexing the column names

Comment: Can you try the code in the Answer I have given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
df = pd.read_excel(response.content, header=None)
df = df.dropna(how="all").dropna(how="all", axis=1)
df = df.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
headers = df.iloc[0]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)
new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

csv file sample for reproducible example

```
,,
,,
col1,col2,col3
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

**Code**

```
import io
txt = ''',,
,,
col1,col2,col3
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9'''

# Extract some columns (like 0, 1) from a file to find all values are NaN.
sample = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), usecols=[0, 1], header=None)
```

sample

```
      0     1
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2  col1  col2
3     1     4
4     2     5
5     3     6
```

you can use ``

get dataframe

```
n = sample.isna().all(axis=1).cummin().sum()
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), header=n)
```

df

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
```

I recommend reloading the file after determining the number of rows to skip due to the data type. You can load only a subset of columns into a DataFrame as a sample to determine the number of rows to skip.

The above code creates an example CSV file for everyone's practice. In summary, you can use the following code:

```
sample = pd.read_excel('your_file_path', usecols=[0, 1], header=None)
n = sample.isna().all(axis=1).cummin().sum()
df = pd.read_excel('your_file_path', header=n)
```